# How to load parts of a large tilemap like chunks in Unity 2d?

Tags: unity, 2d, tilemap, maps, loading

[image]

[image]

[image]
[image]

I use more pictures so you can understand my opinion better.
[Here is the video link I recorded](https://streamable.com/u2idho?fbclid=IwAR25uWEdmYONomed0cUuwoDZMEsoZjJDd1m3lHIJT6HbEP7ysDkzK6I0ECM).

My code has a problem that I use for to render it and cause it to "lag" for 1-5 seconds, so I need to optimize it, and I found one way is to use chunks, and why I don't use the tilemap and it drops my fps

[This links to my map data and my code](https://pastebin.com/akR2QgGC).

```
// this is my function I use to create clone game object
if (Vector3.Distance(target.position, topLeft) < 25f
         || Vector3.Distance(target.position, topRight) < 25f
         || Vector3.Distance(target.position, bottomLeft) < 25f
         || Vector3.Distance(target.position, bottomRight) < 25f)
{
    // My code is currently running "fine", but when it renders the 
    // map in 1-2s it will drop fps because of the for loop, then it will increase again
    xMin = xMin - 1;
    xMax = xMax + 1;

    yMin = yMin - 1;
    yMax = yMax + 1;

    GetCircumjacent();
    for (int x = xMin; x < xMax; x++)
    {
        for (int y = yMin; y < yMax; y++)
        {
            if (x == xMin || y == yMin || x == xMax - 1 || y == yMax - 1)
            {
                try
                {
                    int mapX = xCenter + x;
                    int mapY = yCenter + y;
                    
                    // this is when I get the prefabs from the array prefabs I added
                    GameObject clone = Instantiate(prefabs[map[mapX, mapY]], this.transform);
                    clone.transform.position = zero + new Vector3(x, y);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    Debug.Log("Error: Index out of range");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

private void GetCircumjacent()
{
    topLeft = zero + new Vector3(xMin, yMax - 1);
    topRight = zero + new Vector3(xMax - 1, yMax - 1);

    bottomLeft = zero + new Vector3(xMin, yMin);
    bottomRight = zero + new Vector3(xMax - 1, yMin);
}
```

Comment: Your question would be even better if you post the code that you currently use

Comment: oh yeah, i know that, but i'm not at home, i can't upload it, i will upload it, thank you so much, i hope you can help me after i edit it again

Comment: Your diagrams look like a sensible solution to this problem. Where have you run into difficulty implementing the solution you've shown here?

Comment: guys can see my code, i edited it, please see it :(

Comment: I won't look at code on an external site, but you're welcome to include a minimal complete verifiable example of the problem in the question itself. Be sure to explain what the problem in this code is so we can help you fix it.

Comment: thank you so much bro, i edited it

Comment: Seems like you are cloning prefabs on every pass, even when cell is occupied already. Over time this results in huge number of identical prefabs laying on top of each other. You need some way to track if cell is occupied already, and skip prefab instantiation in that case.